# No network on android studio emulator when target nougat with arm

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, arm, emulation

Testing my app on android studio emulator, app needs to connect to network.
It works fine below Android 7.0, both x86 and arm.
But if I run it on Android 7.0 or 7.1.1, it only works on x86.
Seems there's no network on Android 7.0 or 7.1.1 with arm.
And when I open the chrome, trying www.google.com,It failed.

[image]

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the network status icon in your screen shot, it looks like you running an out of date system image. There were some recent updates to emulator system images to address network connectivity issues.  If you are running ARM, make sure running revision 4 of "Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image", and v26.1.0 of the Android Emulator and the network should work, per the attached screenshot.
[image]

That being said, is there a reason why you do not want to use x86 emulator System images? They are significantly faster than the ARM emulator system images. Moreover, the Google Play Store is now installed on the x86 system images from API 24 onwards.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day... really helpful.After updating my Android Emulator to 26.1.0, it works fine.